# What API can be used to change windows account information remotely?

Tags: passwords, wmi, acl, samba, smb

What API is available to change windows account passwords remotely?  Assuming I have the proper credentials to change the windows accounts, I need to write software that can do so remotely.

The software will run on Linux, and so far it appears that [SMB](http://www.samba-tng.org/docs/tng/htmldocs/smbpasswd.8.html) may have some functionality in this area, but I need either an API, library, code, or even the right key words to help me figure out how to search for solutions or an approach to solving this problem.

I've found [Wmi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) client on Linux but as far as I understand there seems to be [issues](http://blogs.balabit.com/2010/09/18/wmi-client-for-linux/) with it.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tag this as, but you'll probably get more attention if you tag it with something with more followers such as linux and python(if that's the language you're intending to use)

Comment: @Earlz: thanks for the suggestion, if available python is indeed my language of choice.

Comment: @Adam Davis: thanks for the edit. It just looks perfect.

Comment: Can you have something installed on the target Windows machine, or do you have a requirement that it be a plain vanilla Windows install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
smbpasswd -r machine -U user.
```

You can use [wmi-client](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man1/winexe.1.html), but on the other hand that does not work  on windows 2008 server with domain controller and the password is passed in the network without encryption.

Answer (score 1):

The *smbpasswd* command that is part of Samba allows you to change the password on remote machines. E.g.

```
smbpasswd -r MACHINE -U USER
```

You should be able to just invoke that command from your favorite programming language; the next version of Samba will have some Python APIs that probably also allow you to do this from within Python.